# Using Photobucket api with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, photobucket

I am trying to use Photobucket(API) as a image uploading option in my website.
Is there any available gem to do this? or should i use things like REST to achieve this?

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: +1 . I am also searching any other option other than Amazon S3.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out I'm trying to figure out the same?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I really found was this https://bitbucket.org/photobucket/api-ruby/src/7b69e473fb9fd5b4d37e2ad7f266500e45ef524b/example.rb?at=default. They are using the oauth rubygem to talk to photobucket, still a lot of manual process involved. It is also still using REST.

I would say the easiest way it going ahead and using REST following http://pic.photobucket.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/PhotobucketPublicHelp.htm and http://pic.photobucket.com/dev_help/WebHelpPublic/Content/FAQ/FAQOverview.htm to get you started.

I haven't done a REST client in ruby but this gem looks pretty good https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client.

I would recommend, assuming you have the time, making a photobucket ruby gem and wrapping the REST calls in useful class abstractions. It is great for the community, forces you to follow good practices(to a certain extent) and will provide great experience to put on a resume/talk about in an interview.